# Help with /scoreboard objective score abuse!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I set up a scoreboard which is counting mined diamond ores. Score is displayed in the sidebar. The problem is that players are able to abuse the score with silk touch, they mine and place ores repeatedly.

How can I get the scoreboard to show the wanted value?

Comment: Maybe a "picked up diamond scoreboard" instead?

Comment: @ExperimentalRocket Then people could repeatedly throw and pick up diamonds to increase their score.

Comment: Has one of the answers helped you? Then you can mark it as accepted using the check mark to indicate that your problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

You add to the score whenever the player mines diamond ore and you remove from the score whenever the player places the diamond ore. This could still be slightly inaccurate when players give each other the diamond ore block, but in general, this won't cause an infinite score abuse.

Comment: This would at least keep the total score of all players equal to the total ore blocks they mined in the world, which is probably ok for most use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Use another scoreboard to store the **ACTUAL** diamond ore mined. Use a **tag** to mark to player with `{SelectedItem:{tag:{ench:[{id:33s}]}}}` NBT (having silk touch enchantment).

Then, add 1 to the ACTUAL score if the player have score mined diamond ore >0 and don't have the tag (don't holding tool with silk touch enchantment.)

Not sure if it is accurate enough(maybe players can quickly switch items...maybe...), but it should be much more accurate than other methods.

edit: forgot to say that you have to reset the mine block score every tick after you check to score.